# Jackson can't deserialize MongoDB object passed through REST

Tags: java, mongodb, rest, jackson, dropwizard

Trying to set up an application to display MongoDB nested data (two levels of nesting and embedding) in a web application (for business analysis).

I'm using Dropwizard, so I copied the [dropwizard-mongo](https://github.com/meltmedia/dropwizard-mongo) [example](https://github.com/meltmedia/dropwizard-mongo/tree/develop/example), reduced it to the necessary parts (no delete, no insert, no metrics or anything).

App.java

```
package test;


import io.dropwizard.Application;
import io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap;
import io.dropwizard.setup.Environment;

import com.meltmedia.dropwizard.mongo.MongoBundle;
import test.Res;

public class App extends Application<Config> {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new App().run(args);
  }

  MongoBundle<Config> mongoBundle;

  @Override
  public void initialize(Bootstrap<Config> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addBundle(mongoBundle =
        MongoBundle.<Config> builder()
            .withConfiguration(Config::getMongo).build());
  }

  @Override
  public void run(Config config, Environment env) throws Exception {
    env.jersey().register(new Res(mongoBundle.getDB()));
  }


}
```

Res.java (Resource class)

```
package test;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;


import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;

import org.jongo.Jongo;
import org.jongo.MongoCollection;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.mongodb.DB;

@Path("/")
public class Res {

  DB database;
  Jongo jongo;

  public Res(DB database) {
    this.database = database;
    this.jongo = new Jongo(database);
  }

  @GET
  @Produces("application/json")
  public Set<String> collectionNames() {
    return database.getCollectionNames();
  }

  @Path("{collectionName}")
  public CollectionResource collection(@PathParam("collectionName") String name) {
    return new CollectionResource(jongo.getCollection(name));
  }

  public class CollectionResource {

    MongoCollection collection;

    public CollectionResource(MongoCollection collection) {
      this.collection = collection;
    }

    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public List<String> list() {
      return collection.distinct("_id").as(String.class);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("{id}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public ObjectNode getDocument(@PathParam("id") String id) {
      ObjectNode node = collection.findOne("{_id: #}", id).as(ObjectNode.class);
      if (node == null) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).build());
      }
      return node;
    }

  }

}
```

I can curl to / and will get the collections returned, so I'll say the connection to the DB works. However, if I curl any of the collections, be it the actual data or a dummy with just plain KVP of letters and numbers or even just an empty object (_id only), I always get

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: org.bson.types.ObjectId cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Given I hardly did anything to the example, I'm somewhat at loss for ideas what to do about this.

Comment: I am sorry to hear that the example is causing you issues.  This is a type conversion problem.  To get reads working, you would need to register https://github.com/michel-kraemer/bson4jackson with the object mapper inside Jongo.  I do not think you could get a write command to work properly using the generic types, since it would put String values for _id, instead of actual ObjectIds.  I will see about adding an example that covers Mongo specific types.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `POST` method creating data or are you using an existing collection?

You can see [here](https://github.com/meltmedia/dropwizard-mongo/blob/develop/example/src/main/java/com/meltmedia/dropwizard/mongo/example/resources/RootResource.java#L102) that in their example, they are are explicitly treating `_id` as a `String` and NOT an `ObjectId`.  My guess is that was to get around the very issue you are seeing here.

Jongo has [many ways of mapping an `ObjectId`](http://jongo.org/#mapping), but they all requiring using a custom POJO and annotating the `id` field so they wont be as flexible as the example shown.

If possible, convert all your `_id` fields in the database to be plain strings, otherwise you will need to find someway to deal with the `ObjectId` type (either typing to to a POJO or [modifying the Jongo Mapper](http://jongo.org/#advanced) perhaps).

Good Luck :)

Comment: It's an existing collection. Since I made better progress in my attempt at doing this in Spring, I'm pursuing that path and haven't continued with dropwizard. Appreciate your help!